# Wanna disable the column (row no:) from sorting usage by Tabulator js plugin

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable, tabulator

How can I make all columns on a Tabulator table auto sort except the first column[image][image]

I have tried `sortable:false` & `headerSort:false`.

img(1) Initial table

img(2) Sorting table at Name: column.

(Target : Remaining the No: value from 1 to 6 by ascending order even Name: order change.)

Could you please help me to find a solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please try rephrasing your question, are you trying to have all columns auto sort except the first column that contains the row numbers?

Comment: Thanks....I corrected my question as your expressions.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle or share sample code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8daog647/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per;

https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/861

"You need to set the headerSort property in the column definition object for the column you want to not be sortable, not on the table as a whole. the sortable property you are currently using in your column definition was removed in version 3.0"

```
$("#mytable").tabulator({
    height:205,                         // Set height of table, this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed
    //layout:"fitColumns",              // Fit columns to width of table (optional)
    resizableColumns:false,             // Disable column resize
    responsiveLayout:true,              // Enable responsive layouts
    placeholder:"No Data Available",    // Display message to user on empty table
    initialSort:[                       // Define the sort order:
        {column:"altitude",     dir:"asc"},     // 1'st // THIS IS WHAT YOU'RE LOOKING FOR I ASSUMEN
    ],
    columns:[
        {title:"Flight", field:"flight", headerSort:false, responsive:0, align:"left"}, // , width:250},
        {title:"CallSig", field:"callsign", headerSort:false, responsive:3},
...
```

Further reading: http://tabulator.info/docs/3.3#sorting

EDIT: You can set sorting programmatically;

```
$("#example-table").tabulator("setSort", "age", "asc");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: initialSort setting is for only page loading time and headerSort property is for only disable the header click sorting. That has been sorting when operate other columns sorting. :(
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:"292px",    initialSort:[{column:"no", dir:"asc"},],
    columns:[ //Define Table Columns
        {title:"No", field:"no", width:50, frozen:true, headerSort: false},
        {title:"Name", field:"name", width:300, frozen:true, headerSortStartingDir:"desc"},
        {title:"Age", field:"age", width:300, align:"left", formatter:"progress"},
    ]
});

Comment: I'm sorry but this does not make it any clearer as to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for my weak question. You can see here https://jsfiddle.net/8daog647/ sample code.

Comment: What do you mean by "auto sort", there are three types of sorting you can do on Tabulator, there is the initialSort option which is used to set the sort on the data when it is loaded into the table, there is the headerSort property that lets you choose whether a user can sort the data by clicking on the column header. And there is the sort function that can be used for programatically triggering the sort. Those are the ONLY three options. Could you try describing your problem be explaining the behaviour you are looking for and not using the term "autosort"

Comment: I used headerSort property to all of columns except the first column. First Row is row number column. The first column had been sorted when i clicked to other columns' header. I want to let remain the row number column does not sort.

Comment: Finally, I found formatter:"rownum" just used that  instead of creating of row number by programming. It makes row number still remain as before. Thanks & sorry for my carelessness.

Comment: Mr.Oli May I know one thing?  How can show pagination bar at the upper side of table instead of table bottom.